# Optimized way to check distinct values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I am looking for an answer where from a column (Table of around 50k records) I just need to check out whether the column has at least two distinct values in it.

```
Select Count(Distinct ColumnA)
from tableX
```

The above query gives me the output, but it is not the optimized way as I just want an answer in Boolean

i.e. Count Is more than 1 Or No?

Further the no of records increase in tableX will worsen the query performance, I am looking something which is independent of table record counts.
Any help is appreciated :) thanks.

Comment: you should try to "limit 1", so it stop looking after first distinct

Comment: You mean Set ROWCOUNT 2 AND THEN AGAIN RESET IT BACK TO 0. But setting rowcount will it operate after distinct is applied on result set. Although i am getting the desired result with this, but just wanted to check on this. Thanks

Comment: yea, my bad, Select Count(Distinct ColumnA) from tableX  limit 2

Comment: Does Limit work with Sql server 2005? I am sorry I forgot to mention Sql Server 2005 am working on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) = 2 THEN 'Yes'
         ELSE 'No'
       END
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 ColumnA
        FROM tableX
        WHERE ColumnA IS NOT NULL) T
```

Will likely give you a plan that stops processing after the first two `DISTINCT` values are found.

Check that the execution plan uses a stream aggregate or a `HASH MATCH (FLOW DISTINCT)` as they are both non blocking. If the `DISTINCT` is implemented as a `HASH MATCH` without `(FLOW DISTINCT)` then this is blocking and all rows will still be processed.

e.g. Both these plans stop without processing all rows.

[image: Plan]

Comment: Seems to be working as expected. I can see Stream Aggregate and distinct flow as logical operation for Hash Match. Thanks